# how to nudge substitutions in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

i have the following where a, b, c, d are all sympy symbols

```
p = a + b + 2*c + d
q = a + b + c + d
```

i wanted to do this:

```
p = p.subs(a + b + c + d, q)
```

and wanted to get this:

```
p = q + c
```

but p remains unchanged.

what should i be doing to get to p = q + c?

the matching performed by subs() seems to be looking for strict ordering, and hence it didn't split up the '2*c' term.

should i be using replace() instead of subs().

EDIT:
code as follows:

```
import sympy

a, b, c, d = sympy.symbols('a,b,c,d')

p = a + b + 2*c + d
q = a + b + c + d

r = p.subs(a + b + c + d, q)

print r
```

EDIT #2

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sympy/b_Yv6s15Y0Q

my problem is similar to the groups.google link, just that in that case subs() do its job.

Comment: Can you give us the whole code?

Comment: the code is added into the original post!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First a comment about your code: since you define q to be the sum a+b+c+d you will never see the change, even if it did work (but it doesn't). Something else that does work is the following:

```
>>> p = a + b + 2*c + d
>>> q = var('q')
>>> p.extract_additively(a+b+c+d) + q
c + q
```

There is also an extract_multiplicatively method.

Comment: thanks for your answer!
looks like i might have to write a custom function to reduce the expression to be represented more concisely. 

i have a related question sympy question then, in my situation, i have p and q expressions, both already defined (as in the original question), is there a way to concisely represent p in terms of q? or q will always be expanded out into its a,b,c,d terms?

Comment: if not, i guess my customized function will just have to 'blind' q first, and hack around the extract_additively function on p or something.